# How to stack columns with different height in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

This is the goal that I wanted to achieve

[image]

This is what I currently have

I do not want to use row-span-3 on the 3rd column of the top as it would make it big I currently have this one for now.

As you can see in the second image for the 1st rows all the columns have the same height and I wanted to avoid that. The columns should have a flexible height and can be stacked. The partner id and and partner code columns should be smaller without being affected by the 3rd column.

[image]

````html
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-5 gap-4 text-white">
            <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8">
                <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Promo code</h1>
                <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
                    {{ promocode }}
                    <button
                        style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                    >
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto" />
                    </button>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 max-h-[250px]">
                <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Partner ID</h1>
                <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
                    {{ id }}
                    <button
                        style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                    >
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto" />
                    </button>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-span-2 row-span-3 col-start-1 row-start-2">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 col-span-2 col-start-3 row-start-1">
                <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Custom Partner Link</h1>
                <h1 class="text-white font-semibold mb-5 text-xl flex flex-row">
                    {{ partnerLink }}
                    <button
                        style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                    >
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto" />
                    </button>
                </h1>
                <button class="bg-[#1b57c4] font-semibold px-12 py-2 rounded-lg">
                    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-play" class="ml-auto" />
                    How It Works?
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-start-3 row-start-2">8</div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-start-4 row-start-2">9</div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-start-3 row-start-3">10</div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-start-4 row-start-3">11</div>
            <div class="border-2 border col-span-2 col-start-3 row-start-4">12</div>
        </div>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could consider splitting the top row into two row tracks of `min-content` and `1fr` sizing. Have the top right element span 2 rows, thus it would be greater in height than the first left column elements:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-[min-content_repeat(5,1fr)] gap-4 text-white">
  <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8">
    <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Promo code</h1>
    <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
      {{ promocode }}
      <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
      </button>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 max-h-[250px]">
    <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Partner ID</h1>
    <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
      {{ id }}
      <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
      </button>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-span-2 row-span-4 col-start-1 row-start-2">
  </div>
  <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 col-span-2 col-start-3 row-start-1 row-end-3">
    <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Custom Partner Link</h1>
    <h1 class="text-white font-semibold mb-5 text-xl flex flex-row">
      {{ partnerLink }}
      <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
      </button>
    </h1>
    <button class="bg-[#1b57c4] font-semibold px-12 py-2 rounded-lg">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-play" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        How It Works?
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-start-3 row-start-3">8</div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-start-4 row-start-3">9</div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-start-3 row-start-4">10</div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-start-4 row-start-4">11</div>
  <div class="border-2 border col-span-2 col-start-3 row-start-5">12</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could consider splitting the layout into two separate grid systems:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-white">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 auto-rows-min">
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Promo code</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ promocode }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 max-h-[250px]">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Partner ID</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ id }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="border-2 border col-span-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-5 gap-4">
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 col-span-2">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Custom Partner Link</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold mb-5 text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ partnerLink }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
            <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
      <button class="bg-[#1b57c4] font-semibold px-12 py-2 rounded-lg">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-play" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
          How It Works?
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="border-2 border">8</div>
    <div class="border-2 border">9</div>
    <div class="border-2 border">10</div>
    <div class="border-2 border">11</div>
    <div class="border-2 border col-span-2">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or flex layouts:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-white">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 flex-1">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Promo code</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ promocode }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 max-h-[250px] flex-1">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Partner ID</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ id }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-full">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
    <div class="bg-[#0d1129] rounded-lg mb-5 p-8 basis-full">
      <h1 class="text-[#636da8] uppercase">Custom Partner Link</h1>
      <h1 class="text-white font-semibold mb-5 text-xl flex flex-row">
        {{ partnerLink }}
        <button style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: auto; color: #1b57c4" class="cursor-pointer">
            <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-copy" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
        </button>
      </h1>
      <button class="bg-[#1b57c4] font-semibold px-12 py-2 rounded-lg">
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-play" class="ml-auto"></font-awesome-icon>
          How It Works?
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-1/3 grow">8</div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-1/3 grow">9</div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-1/3 grow">10</div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-1/3 grow">11</div>
    <div class="border-2 border basis-full">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd example isn't exactly working as well. Although the 1st one seems nearly got it